# How can I manually download a snap package? For example, with wget?

Tags: package-management, download, snap

How can I manually download a snap package?  Preferably as a non-root user with `wget`?

For example, the Snapcraft page for Chromium is here:

- https://snapcraft.io/chromium

How can I find the URL(s) at which Chromium's snap files can be downloaded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

snap packages are not meant to be downloaded manually so it's quite tricky. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075694/how-to-get-snap-download-url) on the [Ubuntu side of StackExchange.](https://askubuntu.com/)

As a non-root user you can use `curl` to retrieve all the information about a package like so :

```bsh
curl -H 'Snap-Device-Series: 16' http://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/info/chromium >> chromium.info
```

If you want another package you just have to replace `chromium` by another pacakge name. The previous command will copy all the information about the package into a `chromium.info` file. If a JSON processor like `jq` is installed on your system you can pipe the result of `curl` to `jq` with

```bsh
curl -H 'Snap-Device-Series: 16' http://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/info/chromium | jq
```

to ease your reading. The result will contain many entries for various channels and architectures, look for the one that fits you best. You will find something like

```
{
    "channel": {
    "architecture": "arm64",
    "name": "edge",
    "released-at": "2019-12-21T08:18:39.959452+00:00",
    "risk": "edge",
    "track": "latest"
    },
    "created-at": "2019-12-21T08:16:39.600827+00:00",
    "download": {
    "deltas": [],
    "sha3-384": "92c0824bfc8c136a2b8179fcdd14647f7174dd3103397e107b0100decc1ac8b29eb22fbba61949a4e1fdf1a282f2a8e0",
    "size": 144859136,
    "url": "https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/download/XKEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R_985.snap"
  },
  "revision": 985,
  "type": "app",
  "version": "80.0.3987.16"
},
```

and now you can `wget` the given URL to download your package file.

Comment: Based on the above answer and the `jq` utility, the URL can be extracted in the following one-liner:

`curl -s -H 'Snap-Device-Series: 16' http://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/info/chromium | jq '."channel-map" | map(select(.channel.architecture == "amd64" and .channel.name == "stable")) | .[0].download.url'`

Answer (score 4):

You can download snaps with `snap download (snapname)` which will grab the latest stable release snap file and an assertion file. Once downloaded you can install with `snap ack (file.assert)` and `snap install ./file.snap`.

Comment: I like this way best! If only there were a `snap download --recursive`